# Oculus Rift raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am currently using unity with a Oculus rift running a OVRCameraRig and a script attached to the CenterEyeAnchor on it. This script uses the following code.

```
GameObject dot;
    void Start () {
        dot = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        dot.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        dot.layer = 2;
        dot.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    }

void Update () {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, out hit, 80.0f))
        {
            dot.transform.position = hit.point;               
        }
        else
        {
            dot.transform.position = transform.forward * 80 + transform.position;
        }
    }
```

When I run the following code without a rift headset plugged in, the RayCast collides with all objects (whilst moving the OVRCameraRig within the scene) however if i restart the program with my rift plugged in, the raycast goes through all objects and hence moves the ball 80 units away from you.
I am wondering why the RayCasts behaviour would change after i plug in the headset and if there would be a way to stop this.

Edit: While debugging the following code it seems that when the rift is connected the raycast always fails to hit on all objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a simple mistype of using Vector3.forward in the Raycast rather than transform.forward